# Binary fission in amoeba

Tags: reproduction, asexual-reproduction

When a parent amoeba undergoes binary fission, two amoeba are obtained. Are those two amoebas, both daughter, or 1 parent and 1 daughter?

Comment: During binary fission in unicellular eukaryotes ,the nucleus of parent organism divide into two it is followed by the divison of cytoplasm so two daughter cells of almost equal in size are formed

Comment: Binary fission is found in unicellular organisms like amoeba.After attaining an optimum size,the adult individual undergoes a simple division to firm two daughter cells of equal size. During this fission in amoeba,first of all nuclear division takes place followed by cleavage of cytoplasm into equal parts.

Comment: I think concept of parents and offspring (daughters) is not very useful for unicellular organisms.

Answer (score 2):

> In binary fission, the fully grown parent cell splits into two halves, producing two new cells. After replicating its genetic material, the cell divides into two nearly equal sized daughter cells. The genetic material is also equally split. The daughter cells are genetically identical (unless a mutation occurs during replication).

Source: [Binary Fission - Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_fission)

This corroborates with what I was taught in school as well.

A quick [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=binary+fission&tbm=isch) also shows that most diagrams on the subject involve one parent producing 2 daughter cells.

Comment: But it doesnt make sense. The parent is still alive, how can we call it daughter?

Comment: From [here](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Binary_fission) "Fission is a process by which an unicellular organism splits(/divides) to form two or more new organisms.When the parent organism splits to form many new organism it is called multiple fission. If the parent organism splits(/divides) to form two new organism it's called binary fission. When this happens **the parent ceases to exist** and two new organism is formed. Amoeba reproduces with the help of binary fission."